# Aggregated Query Too many query rows

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits, aggregateresult

I have this aggregated query which seems to return only 1050 rows but still I am getting a limit exception. This is the APEX query:

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(ID) cnt, FISCAL_YEAR(CreatedDate) year, FISCAL_MONTH(CreatedDate) month, Country country 
FROM Lead 
WHERE Should_Include_in_Marketing_Performance__c = true 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Country, FISCAL_YEAR(CreatedDate), FISCAL_MONTH(CreatedDate))];
```

This is the actual log:

> 08:32:42:006 SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [66]|Aggregations:0|SELECT
>   COUNT_DISTINCT(ID) cnt, FISCAL_YEAR(CreatedDate) year,
>   FISCAL_MONTH(CreatedDate) month, Country country FROM Lead WHERE
>   Should_Include_in_Marketing_Performance__c = TRUE GROUP BY
>   ROLLUP(Country, FISCAL_YEAR(CreatedDate), FISCAL_MONTH(CreatedDate))
>
> 08:32:46:228 SOQL_EXECUTE_END [66]|**Rows:1050**
>
> 08:32:46:229 EXCEPTION_THROWN [66]|System.LimitException: **Too many
>   query rows: 50001**

Any ideas why I am hitting the limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of rows aggregated count against the 50,000 record limit. The "Rows" value you're seeing are the number of aggregate rows that were returned; this has a limit of 2,000 rows per query; if you exceed that, you'll get a different sort of error. Without knowing more, it's hard to tell what you'll need to do, but it may involve writing a batch class, using the @ReadOnly annotation, or filtering the data differently. This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm):

> Queries that include aggregate functions are subject to the same governor limits as other SOQL queries for the total number of records returned. **This limit includes any records included in the aggregation**, not just the number of rows returned by the query. If you encounter this limit, you should add a condition to the WHERE clause to reduce the amount of records processed by the query. *(Emphasis added)*

Comment: @sdfcfox I am trying to do a GROUP BY ROLLUP query on Leads with some WHERE condition. I tried doing the same in a batch with size 50K but I am getting this error now: "Aggregate query does not support queryMore()". I cannot find a way to do this aggregated query on many leads?

Comment: @Dedo Correct. Aggregate results are limited to 2,000 results. You may need to do the aggregation in your batch class manually by using Database.Stateful.

Comment: @sdfcfox this is frustrating, I know I will get less than 2000 results but the dataset I am aggregating is larger than 50K

Comment: @sfdcfox is there a solution to this?