# Count_Distinct: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, soql, schedulebatch

I cannot understand why I am receiving the following error:

Too many query rows: 50001

The first two queries work perfectly when using COUNT( id), but the last two Contacts_Reached_TR_120_Query and Accounts_Reached_TR_120_Query receive this error. Is there something wrong with using COUNT_DISTINCT. I also would like to note that the Aggregate Result is only returning six rows.

```
String Contacts_Created_TR_120_Query = 'SELECT CreatedByID SDR_ID, COUNT( id ) result FROM Contact Where CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:120 AND CreatedById in :ListOfIDs GROUP BY CreatedById';
DynamicBatchApexAR batch1_TR120      =   new DynamicBatchApexAR('SDR_ID', 'result', 'Contacts_Created_TR_120__c', Contacts_Created_TR_120_Query, SDR_IDs);

String Accounts_Created_TR_120_Query = 'SELECT CreatedByID SDR_ID, COUNT( id ) result FROM Account Where CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:120 AND CreatedById in :ListOfIDs GROUP BY CreatedById';
DynamicBatchApexAR batch2_TR120      =   new DynamicBatchApexAR('SDR_ID', 'result', 'Accounts_Created_TR_120__c', Accounts_Created_TR_120_Query, SDR_IDs);

String Contacts_Reached_TR_120_Query = 'SELECT Ownerid SDR_ID, COUNT_DISTINCT( whoid ) result FROM Task Where ActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:120 AND OwnerId in :ListOfIDs GROUP BY Ownerid';
DynamicBatchApexAR batch3_TR120      =   new DynamicBatchApexAR('SDR_ID', 'result', 'Contacts_Reached_TR_120__c', Contacts_Reached_TR_120_Query, SDR_IDs);

String Accounts_Reached_TR_120_Query = 'SELECT Ownerid SDR_ID, COUNT_DISTINCT( accountid ) result FROM Task Where ActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:120 AND OwnerId in :ListOfIDs GROUP BY Ownerid';
DynamicBatchApexAR batch4_TR120      =   new DynamicBatchApexAR('SDR_ID', 'result', 'Accounts_Reached_TR_120__c', Accounts_Reached_TR_120_Query, SDR_IDs);
```

Comment: What is the API version of this class?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212238/aggregated-query-too-many-query-rows) from [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox):

The number of rows aggregated count against the 50,000 record limit. The "Rows" value you're seeing are the number of aggregate rows that were returned; this has a limit of 2,000 rows per query; if you exceed that, you'll get a different sort of error. Without knowing more, it's hard to tell what you'll need to do, but it may involve writing a batch class, using the @ReadOnly annotation, or filtering the data differently. This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm):

> Queries that include aggregate functions are subject to the same governor limits as other SOQL queries for the total number of records returned. **This limit includes any records included in the aggregation**, not just the number of rows returned by the query. If you encounter this limit, you should add a condition to the WHERE clause to reduce the amount of records processed by the query. *(Emphasis added)*

Comment: I am writing a batch class and still getting this error - Can we just not batch using COUNT_DISTINCT?